# how to check repeating Vowels

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I'm pretty new to python and I'm having trouble with my
if then else statements and I only get is "no repeating vowels" which mean my rep_vowel is still returning 0**

so the program rules are as follows.

if no vowel appears next to itself (e.g. hello), then print:

```
no vowel repeats
```

if exactly one vowel is repeated in sequence at least once (e.g. committee) then print a message that indicates which vowel repeats:

```
only vowel e repeats
```

if more than one vowel repeats (e.g. green door) then print:

```
more than one vowel repeats
```

ignore upper case - lower case differences: assume all the input is always lowercase

```
answer = input("Enter a string: ")
rep_vowel = 0
i = 0
length_Answer = len(answer)
next_string = 1
curChar = answer[0+rep_vowel]

for i in range(0,length_Answer):
    if answer[0 + i] in ["a","e","i","o","u"]:
    i =+ 1 
    next_string = answer[0+i+i]

    if next_string == answer:
        rep_vowel =+ 1

if rep_vowel == 0:
    print("no repeating vowles")
elif rep_vowel > 1:
    print("more than 1 repeating vowels")
else:
    print ("the letter "+ str(curChar) +" repeats")
```

Comment: You have a few logic errors there. Run through your algorithm on paper with a few words and see what it does. You create `curChar`, but you never use it. `next_string = answer[0+i+i]` sets `next_string` to a single char, but then you test it against the whole `answer` string. BTW, using `answer` as the name of the input data is a bit confusing, maybe call it `response` or `word`. Also, `answer[0+i+i]` doesn't make a lot of sense. And there's no point in adding zero to stuff, except for very large values of zero. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have to indent your code.
to say if (condition) then do print('hello') you write it this way:

```
if condition:
   print('hello')
```

Secondly, you are using `i =+ 1`  which is the same as `i=1`
I think you meant    `i +=1`  which is `i = i+1`

Finally, I suggest this code:

```
answer = input("Enter a string: ")
vowel_repeated_count = 0

length_Answer = len(answer)
i=0
while (i <length_Answer-1):
    #we check if it's a vowel
    if answer[i] in ["a","e","i","o","u"]:
        #we check if it's followed by the same vowel
        if answer[i+1] == answer[i]:
            #increment the vowel_repeated_count
            vowel_repeated_count   +=1
            #we save the vowel for the display
            vowel = answer[i]
            #we skip the other same repeated vowels 
            #example: abceeed, we skip the third e
            while (answer[i] == vowel and i < length_Answer-1):
                i +=1
        #we add this incrementation because we're in a while loop
        i +=1


if vowel_repeated_count == 0:
    print("no repeating vowles")
elif vowel_repeated_count == 1:
    print("the letter "+ str(vowel) +" repeats")
else:
    print ("more than 1 repeating vowels")
```

Comment: I like the way you explain your code but I get an error on  the while condition which states  str index out of range

Comment: You're right, I forgot to check that  'i < length_Answer-1'

Answer (score 2):

You have a few mistakes so i'll try to address several of them:

1. You do a lot of `[0 + something]` indexing, which is useless, since `0 + something` always equals to `something`, so yo should just do indexing with `[something]`
2. Changing the value of `i` with `i += 1` is bad because you are already increasing it as part of the loop
3. All you have to do to find a match is simply match the current letter to the next one, if both are the same and they are also vowels, you've found a match.
4. You are initializing unnecessary variables such as `i = 0` only to have them overridden in the next lines

Adding all of those together:

```
answer = input("Enter a string: ")
vowels = "aeiou"
repeats = [] # this list will hold all repeats of vowels

for i in range(len(answer) - 1): # i'll explain the -1 part at the end
    if answer[i] in vowels and answer[i] == answer[i + 1]:
        repeats.append(answer[i])

if len(repeats) == 0:
    print("no repeating vowles")
elif len(repeats) > 1:
    print("more than 1 repeating vowels")
else:
    print("the letter " + repeats[0] + " repeats")
```

This still doesn't take every possible input into account, but it should get you started on a final solution (or perhaps that's enough). For example, input of `teest` will give the correct result but the input of `teeest` doesn't (depends on your definition of correct).

About the `len(answer-1)` range, that's only to make sure we don't go out of bounds when doing `answer[i + 1]`, so we're stopping on the next to last letter instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have some logical errors. It's time consuming to edit that. You can try this, I have modified your code. Hope it will work for you. I have commented beside every important line.

```
answer = input("Enter a string: ")
is_found = {} #a dictionary that will hold information about how many times a vowel found,initially all are 0
is_found["a"]=0
is_found["e"] = 0
is_found['i']=0
is_found['o']=0
is_found['u']=0
vowels =["a","e","i","o","u"]
for i in range(0,len(answer)):
    if answer[i] in vowels:
        is_found[answer[i]] = is_found[answer[i]]+1 # if a vowel found then increase its counter

repeated=0 #let 0 repeated vowel
previously_repeated=False #to trace whether there is a previously repeated character found
curChar=None 
for key,value in is_found.items(): #iterate over dictionary
    if previously_repeated and value>1: #if a vowel found and previously we have another repeated vowel.
        repeated=2
    elif previously_repeated==False and value>1: # we don't have previously repeated vowel but current vowel is repeated
        curChar=key
        previously_repeated=True
        repeated=1

if repeated== 0:
    print("no repeating vowles")
elif repeated> 1:
    print("more than 1 repeating vowels")
else:
    print ("the letter "+ str(curChar) +" repeats")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues with your solution :

1) You never use curChar, i'm guessing you wanted to enter the next_string value into it after the '==' statement.

2) You compare your next_string to answer, this will always be a false statement.

3) Also no need to use [0+i], [i] is good enough

**Basically what you want to do is this flow :**

1) Read current char

2) Compare to next char

3) If equal put into a different variable

4) If happens again raise a flag

**Optional solution :**

```
vowel_list = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
recuring_vowel_boolean_list = [answer[index]==answer[index+1] and answer[index] in vowel_list for index in range(len(answer)-1)]

if not any(recuring_vowel_boolean_list ):
    print("no repeating vowels")
elif (recuring_vowel_boolean_list.count(True) > 1):
    print("More then 1 repeating vowels")
else:
    print("The letter {} repeats".format(answer[recuring_vowel_boolean_list.index(True)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to increment your counter i. In your for loop, it will increment itself each time it goes through the for loop. Also, you need a variable to keep track of how many times the vowel repeats.

```
answer = input("Enter a string: ")
rep_vowel = 0
length_Answer = len(answer)
vowelList=["a","e","i","o","u"]
vowelRepeated = []

#this will go from i=0 to length_Answer-1
for i in range(length_Answer):
    if (answer[i] in vowelList) and (answer[i+1] in vowelList):
        if (answer[i] == answer[i+1]):
            vowelRepeated.append(answer[i])
            repVowel += 1
if rep_vowel==0:
    print("no repeating vowels")
elif rep_vowel==1:
    print("only one vowel repeated:")
    print(vowelRepeated)
else:
    print("multiple vowels repeated:")
    print(vowelRepeated)
```

Answer (score 1):

for such counting, I will prefer to use a dictionary to keep the counting number. Your code has been modified for your reference

```
answer = input("Enter a string: ")
length_Answer = len(answer)

count = dict()

for i in range(length_Answer):
    if answer[i] in ["a","e","i","o","u"]:
        if answer[i+1] == answer[i]:
            if answer[i] in count:
                count[answer[i]] += 1
            else:
                count[answer[i]] = 1 

rep_vowel = len(count)

if rep_vowel == 0:
    print("no repeating vowles")
elif rep_vowel > 1:
    print("more than 1 repeating vowels")
else:
    for k in count:
        vowel = k
    print("the letter " + vowel + " repeats")
```